# R boxplot labeling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm running this code:

```
ggplot(data=price_by_cities_index) + 
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x=State,y=index_housing,color=Rank)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

and the output is:

[image]

How I can add the name of the city in each point? (X-axes)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide reprex.

Nevertheless:

```
+ geom_text(aes(state, index_housing, label = city))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nomad420 Thank's! i have changed visual. i think that plot it's ok. how can i improve further?
i think that label overlap sometime...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqupx.png)

newcode:

```
ggplot(price_by_cities_index, aes(x= State, y= index_housing, label=City))+
geom_point()+theme_minimal() +geom_text(aes(label=City),hjust=1.1, vjust=0, size=2.5, angle = 0)+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90),axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6))
```